# EF Core 1.1 preview1: No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

Tags: asp.net, macos, entity-framework, migration, entity-framework-core

Hi everyone I've the problem with EFCore migration in project on ASP.NET Core.
Some technical info:
OS: macOS

dotnet --version
1.0.0-preview2-003148

Here is my project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "1.1.0-preview1-final",
    "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
      "type": "build",
      "version": "1.1.0-preview1-final"
    },
    "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design": "1.0.2"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ],
      "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
      }
    }
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [
      "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
    ]
  },
  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "TTT"
  }
}
```

I launch "dotnet ef" command from project.json folder.

My actions:

1) dotnet restore

2) dotnet ef

After that I get this error:  "No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef".

I have static "Main" method in Program class (Program.cs).

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What error is encountered after doing the actions listed?

Comment: This error: "No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef""

Comment: How are you typing the command? `dotnet ef` or `dotnet-ef` or `dotnet -ef`?

Comment: I tried commands: "dotnet ef", "dotnet-ef" and get erorr.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-preview3-final"` to the tools section.

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/10/25/announcing-entity-framework-core-1-1-preview-1/ for more info

Comment: All others' answers didn't solve the problem. Only yours do.

Comment: This is the *only* version that works for me at this time.  1.1.0-preview4-final does not exist/cannot be resolved at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.1.0 was released today, so the correct version to add in `project.json` now is `1.1.0-preview4-final`:

```
"tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
}
```

Comment: Please don't use this until the tool will be fixed. It's not compatible with full stack .NET. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40400789/ef-core-1-1-preview1-add-migration-error

Comment: This version does not exist.

Comment: @AJ. it does: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet